# Owl Slider changing img src breaks the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Someone tell me why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Owl/TWtwt/) works and not [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c0s5ec1t/). Am i missing something crucial?

i only changed `img src`to different urls

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tidy up your HTML a bit:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207094959/gundam/images/thumb/e/e6/HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg/1024px-HG_-_Perfect_Strike_Gundam_Box_Art.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but i wanted double rows (2x2 grid) slider. thats why i had 2 <img> in one <div>

Comment: because you really need to pay a little attention. Your code is NOT similar as the one that works, what @ralph.m says is to clean your code and do it correctly. You're repeating `<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">` when in fact you should do it only once, as ralph.m says. Then you can add 2, 3 or whatever rows you want

Comment: Yes, you can still use the two images in each div, rather than one. I've updated the code above to reflect that. That wasn't the part that was causing it to fail. It was the bits Fabio indicated.